# PySide: How to get Visual Studio's Intellisense to pick up PySide library for auto completion?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, pyside, intellisense

I thought I could add the PySide libraries by appending the \PySide folder to my environment's 'Search Paths' but intellisense doesn't seem to be picking anything up. It's picking up my other libraries though.  Any suggestions?

Note: I have PTVS already installed.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled upon this last week.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (VS), so I'm not sure if this works for earlier versions.  Everything you need to know about getting Python up and running in VS is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/PTVS-Installation).

To answer my question:
1) Go to your project's Python Environments> expand> right click on the desired environment> click Install Python Package...
[image]

2) Now, just search for the package you want to install and it should be all set!
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the question and the answer! I use VS 2015 too and do have PySide properly installed and referenced in packages, however Intellisense does not display method signatures for PySide properly - it only lists their names and that's it. So I was wondering if you got the method signatures to work as well?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have yet to discover how to get the method signatures working